# How to wrap axios ajax Promise to retry x number of times before rejecting

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I have a 3rd party ajax library (axios) that returns a Promise when an ajax call is made. I'd like to create a wrapper function ("dispatchAjaxCall" in fiddle) that retries the ajax call until success in this simple example.

The problem I'm having is the wrapper function calls itself on failure to submit another AJAX request, but the then/catch for the end function ("formSubmit") is never called if the ajax call first fails then succeeds. It is called if the ajax call succeeds on the first try.

I'm guessing this is because I'm returning a different Promise from the original. Is there a pattern that is common to creating this wrapper function?

```js
var ajaxCall = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let rand = Math.random()
    if (rand > .5) {
      console.log('from ajaxCall, will resolve in 1 second...')
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(0)
      }, 1000)
    } else {
      console.log('from ajaxCall, will reject in 1 second...')
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject(1)
      }, 1000)
    }
  })
}

var dispatchAjaxCall = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ajaxCall()
    .then(response => {
      console.log('dispatch then. got response:')
      console.log(response)
      resolve(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('dispatch catch. got error:')
      console.log(error)
      console.log("will try again until it works...")
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(dispatchAjaxCall())
      })
    })
  })
}

var formSubmit = dispatchAjaxCall()
  .then(response => {
    console.log('form submit then')
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('form submit catch')
    console.log(error)
  })
```

See console log for simulated success/failure attempts. The problem is line 30 isn't doing what is intended.

Comment: There is a quite neat [axios-retry](https://github.com/softonic/axios-retry) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a recursive call, keep the number of tries in the parent context, and resolve/reject the caller when the callee resolves/rejects:

```js
var ajaxCall = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let rand = Math.random()
      if (rand > .5) {
        console.log('from ajaxCall, will resolve in 1 second...')
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(0)
        }, 1000)
      } else {
        console.log('from ajaxCall, will reject in 1 second...')
        setTimeout(() => {
          reject(1)
        }, 1000)
      }
  })
}

var count = 0;

var dispatchAjaxCall = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ajaxCall()
    .then(response => {
      console.log('dispatch then. got response:')
      console.log(response)
      resolve(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('dispatch catch. got error:')
      console.log(error)
      if (count++ < 3) {
        console.log("Less than 3 tries, will retry")
        dispatchAjaxCall().then(x => resolve(x)).catch(e => reject(e))
      } else {
        reject("More than 3 tries, abort")
      }

    })
  })
}

var formSubmit = dispatchAjaxCall()
  .then(response => {
    console.log('form submit then')
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('form submit catch')
    console.log(error)
  })
```